# Nuget Angular DefinitelyTyped specific version

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, typescript, nuget, definitelytyped

At the time of writing this question the most recent version of angular is 1.5. Altought I need/want/must use angular 1.4.8. I can do `install-package angularjs -Version 1.4.8` but I didnt find a way how to install corresponding typings for typescript because versions dont match.

Is there a way how can install safe typings for specific framework version?

Comment: For what it's worth, the API barely changed in 1.5 - the only change I can think of is the addition of the new [`module.component`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) helper. Hopefully someone will be able to give you a solution, but if not, the 1.5 typings won't be completely useless to you.

Comment: You are right that this concrete example is not good one. Anyway there might be cases that the API changes alot and then Ill have compile errors.

Comment: Yeah, for sure - it's definitely better to be in sync if possible.